# batman.js input value

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, batman.js

I want to pass the value of an input field from the view to the controller.
What's the best way to achieve this without binding the input field to a property of the model?
Example:

view:

```
<form data-event-submit="searchHero">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." data-bind="myquery"/>
</form>
```

controller:

```
searchHero: ->
    console.log myquery
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. It feels like the ``params`` object in Batman is useless for anything but named route parameters. Using data bindings for arbitrary search/form inputs just doesn't feel right. I wish there was an easy way to get form input values into the params object easily.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this code binds the input's contents to the `myquery` prop of the controller, so you can access it via standard batman's `get`:

```
searchHero: ->
  console.log @get 'myquery'
```

Comment: Yep, this is how I'd do it too. You're setting an attribute of the controller when you call: `@get('myQuery')` or `@set('myQuery', 'lol omg')`. The view has access to attributes of the controller, so that view binding will bind itself to the same attribute!